# Please make the data SE queries commentable

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

*Not a dupe, my proposal is not about a contact request to the author, it is about comments, like comments below any SE post (which are visible and are reactable by all the community!).*

It would be a very useful feature, because it could enhance the discussion, by creating a community around the data SE.

What is maybe more important: we could contact the query authors about bugs and problems, or unclear side-effects, or any other.